# highcharts filename from canvas

Tags: canvas, highcharts, html5-canvas, filenames

I've been watching way to export the charts Highcharts without calling your server and have found that it can be done with the function canvas.toDataURL the problem is that I can not put a name to the file.

The function is as follows:

```
(function (H) {
H.Chart.prototype.createCanvas = function (tipo) {
    var svg = this.getSVG(),
        width = parseInt(svg.match(/width="([0-9]+)"/)[1]),
        height = parseInt(svg.match(/height="([0-9]+)"/)[1]),
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', height);

    if (canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d')) {

        canvg(canvas,svg);
        var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/"+tipo).replace("image/"+tipo, "image/octet-stream"); 
        // Save locally
        window.location.href=image;
    }else {
        alert ("Your browser doesn't support this feature, please use a modern browser");
    }

}
```

}(Highcharts));

anyone know how I can put a name to the file download?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `filename` attribute, should be fine, like this: `data:application/octet-stream;filename=filename.txt,`

See demo for  tags: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html

Answer (score 0):

An optional approach to download canvas as an image is to use the new download attribute for anchor tags.

This code snippet will dynamically generate the anchor and invoke a click for it to download your canvas image as an image:

After the line:

```
canvg(canvas,svg);
```

add this snippet:

```
var lnk = document.createElement('a'),
    e;

lnk.download = 'myFilename.' + tipo;
lnk.href     = canvas.toDataURL("image/"+tipo);

if (document.createEvent) {
    e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

    lnk.dispatchEvent(e);

} else if (lnk.fireEvent) {

    lnk.fireEvent("onclick");
}
```